# Are sync ajax calls deprecated in Chrome and Firefox as of 28th Sep 2018?

Tags: javascript, ajax, synchronization

I'm struggling to get a definitive answer via Google on whether sync ajax calls on Firefox and Chrome are now fully deprecated?  I've some legacy code which uses this and it would appear Firefox behind the scenes just turns a sync call into an asynch call but doesn't throw an error. Would have saved me a LOT of time and bother if it had just thrown an error.

Most of the sync use cases I can make async.  However there are a few where I can't seem to find an alternative way to code.

Comment: yes, they have been deprecated for several years now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests#Synchronous_request), synchronous requests *that block the main thread* have been deprecated since:

- Firefox 30.0, released in June 2014
- Edge 13, released in May 2015
- The article says Blink 39.0, but there isn't a version of Blink with that number - I think it means Chrome 39.0, released in November 2014

Note that caveat about blocking the main thread - in certain contexts where this isn't the case, synchronous requests aren't deprecated. The main example this is in the context of a [Web Worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API), as running a synchronous request inside a worker doesn't block the main thread!

Comment: Thanks Joe, sometimes what seems like a simple question doesn't seem to have a 'simple' answer on Google.

Comment: @nexar: Yeah, I feel like [Google](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/09/chrome-70-deps-rems) and [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox/Releases/55) are better about publicising deprecations in recent years, but trying to find info on stuff from back in 2014 can be quite tricky!